# html form autcomplete=on is not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, autocomplete, autofill

i want to auto populate username and password from browser cookie, i have added form

> autocomplete="on"

auto fill is not working in IE 11, but it is working both chrome and firefox like charm.

i have enabled autocomplete="on" for username and password fields as well. is there anything additional need to be added to have autofill? need help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, IE11 deliberately ignores this attribute on `input type=password` fields for security reasons.